# How do I tell if a 3rd party vendor framework was built with "Defines Module"?

Tags: swift, ios-frameworks

I have a third party binary framework (written in Objective-C) I need to import into my Swift project.

Without asking the vendor, can I tell if the framework was built with the ["Defines Module" setting turned on](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122) (and thus, can be simply `import`-ed into my Swift files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frameworks that export a module will include a `module.modulemap` file inside a `Modules` directory. By default, that file will look like:

```
framework module FrameworkWithModule {
  umbrella header "FrameworkWithModule.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```